# Neural Network Input Advice

Tags: java, android, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, accelerometer

I am currently doing a project which involves pothole detection and neural networks.  So far, I have an Android phone that reads Accelerometer readings and writes the X,Y,Z Axis aswell as the Amplitude and current timestamp into a CSV file.  The data is then normalized using min-max normalization and uses the Y axis readings from the CSV file.  The problem I am facing for the neural network to learn a pothole is the fact that what data should I feed to the Back Propagation Neural Network?  Shall I set a threshold and when the Y axis reaches this point, get the 5 previous points and 5 points after and then feed the network with 11 inputs? I don't want to overtrain the network nor feed it with data in different positions each time.

Training - I am also starting to gather the data collected and create a training dataset - should I put things such as readings for normal/bumpy roads/speed bumps as well as potholes?  How large should a training set be? or is 'the more data the better it is' actually true?

This is how the pothole data looks like.

[image: Pothole Graph]

This is how the speedbump data looks like.

[image: Speed Bump]

A sample of data collected

```
 X-Axis     Y-Axis    Z-Axis   Timestamp

-0.371827, 8.513097, 5.441484, 165401
-0.601749, 7.976613, 5.326523, 165601
-0.333506, 8.053253, 5.441484, 165801
-0.256866, 8.206534, 5.364844, 166001
0.049697, 8.398136, 5.364844, 166202
-0.371827, 8.436457, 5.211563, 166400
-0.256866, 8.551417, 5.709726, 166601
-0.256866, 8.513097, 5.403164, 166801
-0.333506, 8.474776, 5.709726, 167000
-0.563428, 8.628057, 5.594766, 167201
-0.563428, 7.401808, 4.713398, 167402
-1.981280, 5.447472, 4.406836, 167602    POTHOLE
-0.180225, 5.600753, 5.403164, 167800    POTHOLE
-0.984952, 8.053253, 4.445156, 168001
-1.214874, 8.666378, 5.671406, 168201
-0.525108, 7.210207, 3.870352, 168401
-1.138233, 7.286847, 5.824687, 168600
-0.601749, 10.045910, 5.288203, 168801
-0.180225, 8.206534, 5.173242, 169001
0.279619, 7.861651, 5.518125, 169200
0.202978, 8.934620, 5.824687, 169401
-0.065264, 8.321495, 5.364844, 169601
-0.065264, 8.628057, 5.709726, 169800
-0.716710, 8.014933, 5.748047, 170001
-0.141905, 8.513097, 5.441484, 170200
-0.026944, 8.206534, 5.594766, 170401
-0.601749, 8.168214, 5.058281, 170601
```

**Algorithm**

My proposed algorithm is to set a certain threshold such as **line 12** on the sample data when the Y axis hits a certain threshold such as **<7** then pass the previous 5 points and the 5 points after that to the NN.

Comment: I believe this would be better suited here since it is not a programming question: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to pass only 5 points before and after a threshold to the NN. I think you would want to pass all data to the NN. You would label the data as either a pothole or not.

INPUT (FEATURES) : X, Y and Z
OUTPUT (TARGETS) : 1 (POTHOLE), 0 (NO POTHOLE)

X-Axis     Y-Axis    Z-Axis   TARGET

-0.371827, 8.513097, 5.441484, 0

-0.601749, 7.976613, 5.326523, 0

-0.333506, 8.053253, 5.441484, 0

-0.256866, 8.206534, 5.364844, 0

0.049697, 8.398136, 5.364844, 0

-0.371827, 8.436457, 5.211563, 0

-0.256866, 8.551417, 5.709726, 0

-0.256866, 8.513097, 5.403164, 0

-0.333506, 8.474776, 5.709726, 0

-0.563428, 8.628057, 5.594766, 0

-0.563428, 7.401808, 4.713398, 0

-1.981280, 5.447472, 4.406836, 1

-0.180225, 5.600753, 5.403164, 1

-0.984952, 8.053253, 4.445156, 0

-1.214874, 8.666378, 5.671406, 0

-0.525108, 7.210207, 3.870352, 0

-1.138233, 7.286847, 5.824687, 0

-0.601749, 10.045910, 5.288203, 0

-0.180225, 8.206534, 5.173242, 0

0.279619, 7.861651, 5.518125, 0

0.202978, 8.934620, 5.824687, 0

-0.065264, 8.321495, 5.364844, 0

-0.065264, 8.628057, 5.709726, 0

-0.716710, 8.014933, 5.748047, 0

-0.141905, 8.513097, 5.441484, 0

-0.026944, 8.206534, 5.594766, 0

-0.601749, 8.168214, 5.058281, 0

Comment: This will not work since a speedbump could produce results such as -1.981280, 5.447472, 4.406836, 1

-0.180225, 5.600753, 5.403164, 1

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should send every point +- 5. like when you're in the 20th point you'ill give your nn points from 15 to 25. 
Setting a threshold is a bad idea, because potholes amplitude may change from one to another.
In your training you should take in consideration "small" and "big" potholes.

Could you tell us what nn library you're using ?